# SSL Certificate validation by web browsers

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am a bit confused in understanding the SSL Certificate validation by Web Browsers.

[image]

Looking at the certificate which i see in firefox after connecting to google.com, it has actually three certificates in a chain :

1) GeoTrust Global CA [I guess this is root certificate]

2) Google Internet Authority G2

3) *.google.com

I know that 3 is issued by 2 and 2 is issued by 1. 1 is self-issued.

So, it means google is sending a certificate chain to the browser. How does browser validates all the three certificates ?

Is the order of validation 3->2->1 or 1->2->3 ? I don't think *.google.com will be present in Firefox's trusted certificate list as it cannot store all such website specific certificates.

What is the exact computation done by the browser to establish the trust for the certificate ?

Comment: Voting to move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is initially set up with a set of trust anchors (the CA certificates it trusts). What these are may depend on the operating system or installation.

One of these trust anchors is `GeoTrust Global CA`.

When connecting to `www.google.com`, the server sends its certificate chain, `*.google.com` and `Google Internet Authority G2`.
The browser then verifies that `*.google.com` was indeed signed by `Google Internet Authority G2`. It then looks for the issuer of `Google Internet Authority G2` and tries to match it with the subject of one of the trust anchors it knows (`GeoTrust Global CA`). When it has found a match, it also verifies the signature of `Google Internet Authority G2` using `GeoTrust Global CA`'s public key.

There's a bit more to it than that: checking validity in time and various usage attributes.

Comment: Is the signature of `*.google.com` certificate verified by browser using public key in `Google Internet Authority G2` certificate ?

Comment: Yes, each certificate's signature is verified using its issuer's public key. You build a chain up to a trusted anchor.

Comment: Consider (root)A->B->C->D->E certificate chain. If issuer of D i.e. C is a trust anchor then B and A up in the chain will not be checked, right ?

Comment: Indeed, trust anchors don't have to be "root" CA certs or self-signed.

Comment: Got it. +UpVote for the answer.